# Does Linux have timer coalescing?

Tags: linux

I've been reading about timer coalescing. Windows has had it implemented for a while, and Apple just integrated it in 10.9. I can't find much information about it for linux.

Comment: If you don't get any hits you may have more luck here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ depending on the context. (just don't double post)

Comment: @Enigma there's no need for that, it's perfectly fine here. Your comment encourages cross-posting which is frowned upon

Comment: @Sathya Fixed. I am not in disagreement but just trying to facilitate an answer for the asker since it is specific and there happens to be overlap.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timer_coalescing):

> Timer coalescing
>
> From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>
> Timer coalescing is a computer system energy-saving technique that reduces central processing unit (CPU) power consumption by reducing the precision of software timers to allow the synchronization of process wake-ups, minimizing the number of times the CPU is forced to perform the relatively power-costly operation of entering and exiting idle states.[citation needed]
>
> The Linux kernel added support for deferrable timers in 2.6.22,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timer_coalescing)[2] and controllable "timer slack" for threads in 2.6.28 allowing timer coalescing.[3][4]

Citation 1, in the Wikipedia header, is to:

> Linux 2.6.22 Released, 8 July 2007

So timer coalescing has been around, in Linux, for 6 years.

Comment: Is that an answer though? It says it allows it, but I've never heard about it otherwise. Does it need to be activated? Does Ubuntu come with it on standard for example? I know that some things need to be turned on when building the kernel. This sounds like one of those times.